# jQuery File Upload - angularjs

Tags: php, jquery, angularjs

Mudei um site de um servidor para o outro. Estou a usar esta ferramenta para upload de ficheiros: [aqui](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/angularjs.html). Agora no novo servidor, ao seleccionar mais que um ficheiro não consigo fazer upload da imagem, ou seja, ela nem sequer é carregada na janela. Será algum módulo php em falta no novo servidor?

No ficheiro de logs, dá o seguinte erro:

PHP Warning:  exif_imagetype(): Filename cannot be empty in /caminho_ficheiro/server/php/UploadHandler.php on line 462

Código da linha 462:

```
if (function_exists('exif_imagetype')) {
    switch(exif_imagetype($file_path)){    // ESTA É A LINHA 462
        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
            $extensions = array('jpg', 'jpeg');
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
            $extensions = array('png');
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
            $extensions = array('gif');
            break;
    }
        // Adjust incorrect image file extensions:
        if (!empty($extensions)) {
            $parts = explode('.', $name);
            $extIndex = count($parts) - 1;
            $ext = strtolower(@$parts[$extIndex]);
            if (!in_array($ext, $extensions)) {
                $parts[$extIndex] = $extensions[0];
                $name = implode('.', $parts);
            }
        }
```

O problema à partida não é do codigo, uma vez que no outro servidor funcionava tudo bem.

Comment: Chegou a procurar nos logs do servidor? Alguma mensagem de erro no console?

Comment: não cheguei a procurar, mas vi agora e dá no seguinte ficheiro: UploadHandler.php on line 462

Comment: OK, linha 462, mas e aí, o que tem? A msg de erro é só isso?

Comment: a linha 462 tem o seguinte: 
            switch(exif_imagetype($file_path))

vou actualizar a pergunta e meto um excerto de código maior. obrigado

Comment: Bom, então diria que não é o `exif_imagetype`, pois passou pela condição `if exists`. Parece que o erro é anterior, quem envia o `$file_path` tá mandando a informação incompleta. Consegue retroceder e procurar quem manda isso?

Comment: Coloque a linha em que "$file_path" é declarada...

Comment: o $file_path está a receber o valor aqui: $upload['tmp_name'][$index]

Comment: @brasofilo , este valor está a vir de outra função. A questão é que este código funcionava em outro servidor e não neste, por isso o problema a partida não é do código

Comment: OK, é só por tentar localizar que função/recurso tá originando o problema

Comment: Apenas um palpite baseado nos comentários: quais os valores dos parâmetros `post_max_size` e `upload_max_filesize` no seu php.ini? Qual o tamanho do arquivo que você esta tentando fazer upload?

Comment: @gabrielhof, estou a testar com arquivos pequenos. A questão é que a primeira imagem corre bem mas quando vai para a segunda não.

Comment: E quanto ao parâmetro `max_file_uploads` no php.ini?

Comment: O erro certamente esta nessa função que é chamada, ela está retornando um "$file_path" vazio, pode postar essa função?
Caso não possa, verifica a função linha a linha para tentar descobrir o que está acontecendo...

Comment: @gabrielhof não tenho esse parametro no php.ini

Comment: @Mukotoshi, o problema não deve ser do código, uma vez que no outro servidor o mesmo código funcionada. devo ter alguma restrição a limitar o número de uploads..

Comment: Então tenta setar o valor de `max_file_uploads` pra 10 ou mais. Qualquer coisa, confere na documentação: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ini.core.php#ini.max-file-uploads

Comment: Já deu uma olhada se os diretórios são os mesmos?
Pelo que entendi o $file_path está vindo vazio...
Talvez uma configuração de diretórios ou algo assim.

Answer (score 1):

Ponto 1:
Faz um "echo" da valor de $upload['tmp_name'][$index] para ver o que tem

Ponto 2:
Verifica bem que vc esta recuperando valor com $_FILE porque a partir de PHP5, usar simplismente o nome do input nao funciona mas

Ponto 3:
Verifica que vc coloca multiple no HTML et enctype multipat no tag FORM (enctype="multipart/form-data")

Tambem para receber mas de um documento, vc deve ler a lista com

```
 $_FILES[$nome_input]['tmp_name'][$x]
```

$x depende do numero de documento.

Boa sorte